# Use different font in internet explorer only

Tags: css, internet-explorer, font-family

I am having a real serious trouble using custom face in internet explorer.

I am using a specific font now, with font-face, and it working perfectly fine in modern browser, but i just cannot get it to work in IE.

The method I am using the font in Chrome, Firefox, etc. is the following:

```
font-family: xy;
src: url(fonts/xy.otf);

}
```

Is there a way that IE use another font?

`font-family: xy, iefont, sans;` is not working, because font-typed is specified in a lot of css, and places,

`* {font-family: xy, iefont, sans !important}` is not working becasue it drops the "FontAwesome" family specified earlier.

What is the simpliest to format every text but only for IE?

Comment: Custom font files has some issues rendering on IE, if you use Google Fonts, I believe you will not see such issues.

Comment: Literal answer: [add an IE-specific rule](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11173106/apply-style-only-on-ie). See the other answers, this is not the best way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### IE specific CSS

For browser specific css files I would recommend:

Simple solution, just use this JS library and you can easily apply styles for every browser/os combination:

[BrowserClass.js](http://browserclass.org/)

With this you will get a class name on the body tag with the current name and version of the browser also with the used OS.

After include the file:

```
<script src="js/browserclass.js"></script>
```

For example on Windows 8.1 with the latest ie you will see:

```
<body class="ie ie11 win desktop">
```

And in your style file you can refer by:
(.sass styling)

```
body.ie
  +declare-font-face('Open Sans Light', 'OpenSans-Light-webfont', 200)
```

Note:
Conditional Comments in IE only work for up to IE9!

### SASS mixin

Or If u are using SASS, here's a good mixin:

```
// ---------------------
// Font Face Mixin
// ---------------------
=declare-font-face($font-family, $font-filename, $font-weight: normal, $font-style: normal, $font-stretch: normal)
  @font-face
    font-family: #{$font-family}
    src: url("../fonts/#{$font-filename}.eot")
    src: url("../fonts/#{$font-filename}.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), url("../fonts/#{$font-filename}.svg##{$font-family}") format("svg"), url("../fonts/#{$font-filename}.woff") format("woff"), url("../fonts/#{$font-filename}.ttf") format("truetype")
    font-weight: $font-weight
    font-style: $font-style
    font-stretch: $font-stretch
```

Usage:

```
+declare-font-face('Open Sans Light', 'OpenSans-Light-webfont', 200)
```

Answer (score 1):

Internet explorer uses .eot font files. You can make this work even in IE8. You need to convert your otf fonts to woff, eot, ...

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'MyWebFont';
  src: url('webfont.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: url('webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
       url('webfont.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
       url('webfont.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
       url('webfont.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
}
```

You can use http://www.fontsquirrel.com/ for example to generate these files.

Comment: thanks for your reply, 
i converted my otf file to eot using an online converter, now my fontface code looks like this:

`
@font-face
   {
font-family: xy;
src: url(fonts/xy.otf);
src: url('fonts/xy.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
src: url('fonts/xy.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'); /* IE6-IE8 */

}
`

and still nothing happened in ie (i11, win8)

Comment: Maybe IE 11 has a bug?

Answer (score -2):

You can make use of Conditional Comments in IE.

```
<!--[if IE]>
<style>
.myfontclass {
//your IE specific font here
}
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: no, unfortunately ie conditional has been removed in ie 9,11, with the follwing statement:

_Conditional Comments are not required. There’s no need for “[if IE 10]“ because pages will render (mostly) the same in all modern browsers._

Comment: @user3576148 ok i was unaware of that.thanks for pointing that out.