# IE specific css in CSS file

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I want to add ie specific css to a css file.

```
.center{
margin-top:-40px !important;
}
```

I tried adding

```
 .ie .center{
    margin-top:-40px !important;
    }
```

But this solution doesn't work.Is there any way to do this.

Comment: How are you adding the `.ie` class to your `body`?

Comment: Referred this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11173106/apply-style-only-on-ie and tried it @Paulie_D

Comment: Doesn't answer my question...how are you adding the `.ie` class? Remember conditional comments are only IE9 and below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this in your head tag

```
<!--[if IE]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie.css" class="ie" />
<![endif]-->
```

And paste your css in ie.css

```
.ie .center{
    margin-top:-40px !important;
}
```

If you want to target specific versions of IE then for example

```
<!--[if IE]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie10.css" class="ie10" />
<![endif]-->
```

and your respective css in ie10.css would be

```
.ie10 .center{
        margin-top:-40px !important;
}
```

Get more IE specific hacks [here](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/browser-specific-hacks/) and [here](http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/)

Answer (score 1):

You need to write html IF condition that check if the browser of the client is **IE**.

`<!--[if IE]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie.css" />
<![endif]-->`

Just so you know it will look for all versions of Internet Explorer. In any case I do not recommend using this method, it's best to one css file for all browsers.

Answer (score 1):

use this. you can use this in your normal style.don't need to make other css file for IE.

```
.center{
    margin-top:-40px;   /* IE9 and below */
    margin-top:-40px\9; /* IE8 and below */
    *margin-top:-40px;  /* IE7 and below */
    _margin-top:-40px;  /* IE6 */
}
```

Comment: I need ie specific css for ie10 also

Answer (score 0):

you can either make ie only external stylesheets to target specific versions of IE (or all): http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/

or you can use css hacks for specific IE versions: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/browser-specific-hacks/

or better, one stylesheet for everybody (best solution)

Answer (score 0):

Before I placed my answer, I took a look at the other answers posted and I saw your comment

*" I need ie specific css for ie10 also"*

So I must tell you now that `Conditional Comments` (that's what those IE specific css appliers are called) were disabled for `IE10` and higher since in their point of view, since IE10 they fixed most of the bugs and there was no more need for them.