# Internet Explorer (IE11) ignores CSS break-inside: avoid

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

in a two-column box (`column-count: 2`), the CSS setting `break-inside: avoid` should avoid some content to break from one column into the other. This works fine in Firefox and Chrome (using the appropriate -webkit... names), but not in Internet Explorer.

Here's an example:
https://jsfiddle.net/6s7843ue/1/

Just to ensure that it's not the flexbox within the content:
https://jsfiddle.net/6s7843ue/4/

I did not find any information the IE wouldn't support the `break-inside`, just the opposite: https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/hh772193%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

### Example code

(also see jsFiddle above)

HTML

```
<div class="outer" style="margin: 40px auto; width: 500px; border: 1px solid #0000FF">
    <div class="container">
      This is a rather long text to break into three separate lines, but sometimes won't stay in one column
    </div>    
    <div class="container">
      Should be in next column
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.outer {
    -moz-column-count: 2;
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
    column-count: 2;
    -webkit-column-gap: 1.6em;
    -moz-column-gap: 1.6em;
    column-gap: 1.6em;
}
.container {
  border: 1px solid #AAAAAA;
  margin: 0.2em 0;
  break-inside: avoid;
  page-break-inside: avoid;
  -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change in your container display: flex to display:inline-flex and it works in ie:

```
.container {
  display: -webkit-inline-flex; /* Safari */
  display: inline-flex;
}
```

https://scotch.io/tutorials/a-visual-guide-to-css3-flexbox-properties

Comment: Good idea, in principle, but I need the container to be `display: flex` (sorry, that's only visible from the first jsFiddle, which was a bit too long to post here). I did not find further useful information on this issue on the page you refer to?!

Comment: Thank you. I didn't actually know that there is a `display: inline-flex` corresponding to `display: inline`. Additionally, I have to add `width: 100%` to still see the containers one below the other (because I can have multiple containers or only one ... depends). Now that works - cool. Is there any reason WHY Internet Explorer needs an inline element to have the `break-inside: avoid` working correctly?

Comment: Oh ... just a cross reference to IE conditional stuff - why should we bother Firefox and all the others with such IE hacks: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11173118/336311

Answer (score 4):

Using `display: inline` or `display: inline-flex?` (a suggested by Javier Gonzalez) solves the issue. But it may require some additional CSS because inline elements naturally work different than block elements.

In a side note of https://stackoverflow.com/a/7785711/336311, I found another solution recently: `overflow: hidden`. This has probably something to do with the block formatting contexts ... and it solves the issue as well, without changing the container's flow behavior.

```
.container {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

If somebody has a reasonable explanation for the strange understanding that IE sometimes has of `break-inside: avoid` in combination with a `column-count`, I am still interested.

Answer (score 1):

[According to caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#search=break-inside), IE11:

> Supports the page-break-* alias from the CSS 2.1 specification, but not the break-* properties from the latest spec.

And

> Does not support avoid for page-break-before & page-break-after (only
>   page-break-inside).

Comment: As you can see, the `page-break-inside` attribute (in which IE11 should support `avoid`, according to caniuse.com) is already set. In the developer tools, IE11 tells to use the `break-inside` attribute - but neither of the both attributes seems to have the desired effect :(

Comment: @BurninLeo I can't check but is it possible that, even though it allows setting in dev tools, that it just doesn't work?

Comment: Well, apparently it does not ;) What I wanted to say: The developer tools usually hshow which of the attirbutes is used and which are not - this is quite useful regarding all the -ms- and -webkit- prefixed attributes that make life harder. In my case, IE tells me that `break-inside` is used. I just don't understand why it has no effect... it should.