# HOw to give Padding bottom only for IE

Tags: html, css

I am trying to add padding to a input area using 
   -ms-padding-bottom:8px; in IE11 , but it is not working can someone help me 
please.

Comment: You are required to post a complete but minimal example of the problem markup: [mcve] but I'm not sure such prefixed tags work in IE11.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Apply style ONLY on IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11173106/apply-style-only-on-ie)

Comment: input {
            font-family: GEInspiraSans;
            font-size: 18px;
            color: #2F3133;
            padding-bottom:6px;
           -moz-padding-bottom:8px;
           -ms-padding-bottom:8px;
        }

Comment: It is working for Mozilla not for IE . not sure is there any specific ways to 
   add .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Apply style ONLY on IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11173106/apply-style-only-on-ie)

Answer (score 2):

You can use conditionnal tags in your `<head>` to include a stylesheet only for IE (6 -> 9).

```
<!--[if IE]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="all-ie-only.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

See [this article](https://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html)

For IE 10+ :

```
@media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: active), (-ms-high-contrast: none) {  
    .foo{background: red;}
}
```

For IE 11 only :

```
_:-ms-fullscreen, :root .foo { background: red; }
```

Comment: Conditional comments have been removed from IE and do not work in IE11.