# Need to apply style only to IE/Edge

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

I'm trying to make a site cross browser compatible, i have a fixed image(parallax kinda thing going on), and as some of you may know fixed images and IE/Edge don't mix well, when scrolling with a mouse things get all janky..  so.. i found a fix,add overflow:auto to the body.  Only problem is i have an event listener on the window detecting the Y offset and when it reaches a certain point, a paragraph slides in. With overflow:auto, the y offset isnt detected.. what do i do? Is there a way to only add body: auto on IE/Edge? Or any other workaround?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Apply style ONLY on IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11173106/apply-style-only-on-ie)

Comment: @TrueTiem Conditional comments no longer work in IE after version 9(?) and don't work at all in Edge.

Comment: @Rob you're right, but there are some answers like BrowserDetect or meta https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13478303/correct-way-to-use-modernizr-to-detect-ie/13480430#13480430